# Chromium top bar indicator icon invisible in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, chromium

When using the chromium browser, the indicator icon in the top bar is invisible. As in, there's nothing there, but I can click the empty space and it functions fine. Does anyone know how to fix this?